# is it possible to accurately assess how long it takes one kilobyte to load in a webpage?

Tags: c#, java, .net, html

I would like to know if there is an easy or practical way to determine how long it takes 1 kB on a website to load?

Comment: At which side, client or server ?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Firefox, you can get information on how long various files take to download using the [Firebug plugin](http://getfirebug.com/).  It has a bunch of [network monitoring](http://getfirebug.com/network) features.

Chrome has a console similar to Firebug under tools->developer tools.

This is great for a quick reality check when you are developing, but sometimes you need a little  more.  For instance, you might want to set up a monitoring script to ensure response times aren't creeping up.  [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) is great for this and [supports both Java and C#](http://seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.html#programming-languages).  Another option is to write a quick script using a headless browser like Mechanize ([Ruby](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/), [Perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/)).

I prefer doing this kind of monitoring from the client end as opposed to on the server side because you get a more realistic perspective of what your end users are experiencing.